# Which is the best version of Ubuntu for Aspire 4736z?

Tags: acer, aspire

I'm using Windows but I was desperately trying to use Ubuntu, when installed the version 11.10 something it had a terrible problem: black screen when starting it and sometimes some glitches bothering my work =)

Is there any Acer user that can help me?

Thanks in advance for any help =]

Comment: There isn't a special version of Ubuntu for Acer machines. If you could add the hardware specs, that might help diagnosing the 'terrible problem'. :~)

Comment: He's probably like me it freezes on black screen before login so how do you propose switching to something on the login screen. And on the rare occasion get to login screen mouse freezes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to switch to Unity 2D, which is less dependent on the graphics card. You switch to it by clicking on the button next to the password field when logging in. It's called Ubuntu 2D.